# Session doesn't get saved in symfony with Memcached

Tags: session, symfony, memcached

**I can't store sessions in Memcached server !**

I installed Memcached for PHP and the server 
I run the server with this command

```
memcached -u root -d -m 64 -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211
```

I have this in php.ini in fpm and cli

```
extension=memcached.so
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = unix:/tmp/memcached.sock
```

I followed this for symfony2 
https://gist.github.com/K-Phoen/4327229

You think everything is good ?

You are wrong , because **I don't know !!**
 why the sessions are not stored in memcached

PS : I don't run the memcached server with `service memcached start` because that would be start the server in a different port with nobody as user ..

Help me debug this please.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be telling PHP to connect to the daemon via a socket, but the command you start Memcached with, doesn't include the `-s <file>` parameter, to have it create the socket you want to use.

See: [MemcacheD sockets](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringServer#Unix_Sockets).

Comment: I changed that command to 
`memcached -u root -d -m 64 -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -s /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock`
Note thatI changed the socket to a more permanent place which is var/run/memcached

Comment: I should be able to access sessions normally right  ? 
like `$this->get('request')->getSession()->get('key')`

Comment: Please tell me , Do I persist session normally or should I do something else  ?

Comment: There are some bundles you can use that with some minor configuration turn it into an almost drop-in action. For example, https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle#session-support